# ruby on rails: setting rails routes with :path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I have some routes like this:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'services', :path => 'services/edit', :defaults => { :servicable => 'user' }
  end
end
```

This allows me to have `localhost:3000/users/1/services/edit`

I'm trying to add dynamic path to it.

I tried adding `:as => :edit_services_path`

```
get 'services', :path => 'services/edit', :defaults => { :servicable => 'user' }, :as => :edit_services_path
```

so I can try something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_services_path %>
```

But it gives me error.

```
undefined local variable or method `edit_services_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f856fd5a970>:0x007f856ff18690>
```

I tried searching what the correct way of adding a new path if I'm customizing my path, but haven't had any luck,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the method you specify does yield a dynamic path, just not the one you are trying to use. It yields :

```
services_user GET    /users/:id/services/edit(.:format)                users#services {:servicable=>"user"}
```

And adding the `:as` option creates:

```
edit_services_path_user GET    /users/:id/services/edit(.:format)                users#services {:servicable=>"user"}
```

Which is a bit confusing, since usually `path` is not specified in the path, but used as a helper on the route itself (i.e. `services_user` path would be `services_user_path` with the [path helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939865/named-routes-path-vs-url)) so if the naming maters a lot to you this can be finessed but it is generating the dynamic paths, you can use `rake routes` to view these as you change things as well.

Comment: Ohhhh thanks!! Yeah I was using `rake routes` but I couldn't find `services_user` until you said it and I was looking for it, Thanks!