# Is there a technical reason not to use _url instead of _path in a Rails URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It seems like the general consensus is to use `resource_path` in URLs unless there's an explicit reason to use `resource_url` (like linking to/away from an SSL page, or a different subdomain).

I've run into bugs from time to time from using `_path`, so don't use it anymore, but when I googled this, most people say to use `_path` unless it's necessary to use `_url`. Is there any particular reason that I should not be doing this, or is it just bad form?

Comment: `_url` includes the domain and protocol, `_path` does not. You should be able to come up with with use cases for using one over the other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939865/named-routes-path-vs-url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule of thumb

- Use `_path` for internal links
- Use `_url` for external and CDN type links

### Pros of using _path

- Hassle free domain migration
- Faster page loading since you are reducing the page size

Answer (score 2):

```
root_url => http://localhost:3000/
root_path => /

employees_url => http://localhost:3000/employees
employees_path  # => /employees
```

For more details check these links out:
http://smalltawc.blogspot.de/2013/02/difference-between-url-and-path-in.html
http://viget.com/extend/rails-named-routes-path-vs-url

Comment: Thanks, I do understand the difference, but my question is if there is a reason not to just use `_url` all the time? Aside from just page size (which seems trivial).

Comment: It is just a convention to use "URL" when you need the absolute path and "path" otherwise. It's like starting the name of a model with capital letters.