# A tag's url in rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an anchor tag in my rails app..

```
<a href='app/users/<%= current_user.id %>/personal_settings'> <i class='icon-gear'></i> Personal Settings </a>
```

thing is this gets rendered in many of my html pages. So whenever I click this `<a>` tag the url that goes is like `parent_url + app/users/:id/personal_settings`
Is there any way I can prevent this. Whenever I click this a tag the url should be just `app/users/:id/personal_settings`. no parent tags should come.

Comment: Can you run `rake routes` and show us the output for this particular route?

Comment: Never use hardcoded url. Always use routing helper. the answer mentioned by Mohamed Yakout is correct.

Comment: @jbmyid For the record, I'm not using hardcoded URLs. My solution is also a very viable solution if you don't want to use the `link_to` helper method.

Comment: @richsinn so even if you dont want to use link_to method then also you can use routing helper eg. `<a href='<%= users_personal_settings_path(current_user) %>'> link</a>`

Comment: @jbmyid you obviously did not read my answer. I did use the routing helper (also called a named route). In fact Mohamed Yakout copied my answer after I first posted the usage of the named route. Mohamed's original answer used a hardcoded URL, and I recommended using a named route (you can still see his original answer using the hardcoded URL). Even the example named route `users_personal_settings_path` is my own example I made up that Mohamed copied in his answer! The only extra thing that Mohamed added was the usage of the `link_to` helper.

Comment: @jbmyid and even your own example in your comment is a copy from my answer!

Comment: @richsinn Yes off-course i used your route helper to give an example. And sorry I dint wanted to direct you but Nidhin. I misunderstood who asked question. And my first comment was not for you but for Nidhin. And i suggested answer of mohamed bcs of `link_to` and `block` usage.

Comment: @richsinn And one more thing no body copied your answer. is just helper name and not the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `/` before your url for relative url to root url as the following code:

```
<a href='/app/users/<%= current_user.id %>/personal_settings'> <i class='icon-gear'></i> Personal Settings </a>
```

Or you can use absolute url as the following:

```
<a href='https://www.localhost:3000/app/users/<%= current_user.id %>/personal_settings'> <i class='icon-gear'></i> Personal Settings </a>
```

Read about href for [absolute, and relative](http://www.library.upenn.edu/sitedocs/tutorials/html/atag/atags-abs-rootrel.html) url.

---

You can use helper method [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) as the following:

```
<%= link_to(users_personal_settings(current_user)) do %>
  <i class='icon-gear'></i> "Personal Settings"
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your anchor tag, I'd recommend using the named route for the url in your anchor tag's `href` (**hint**: run `rake routes` to find what your named route is, or you can set your own [named route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-purpose-of-the-rails-router) in your `routes.rb` file) and pass in the `current_user.id` as the parameter to the named route.

For example, if your named route is `users_personal_settings`, then here's how I would set up your `<a>` tag (note the [`_path` extension to the named route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939865/named-routes-path-vs-url)) :

```
<a href='<%= users_personal_settings_path(current_user.id) %>'> 
  <i class='icon-gear'></i> Personal Settings 
</a>
```