# default route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, scaffolding

I had a doubt when i was writing rails code.
In my `link_to` i used my route `order` to show my order. So:

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
    <tr>
      <th><%= order.name %></th>
      <th><%= link_to 'Mostra', order %></th>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

I saw my rake routes and there was a :

```
order GET /orders/:id(.:format) orders#show
```

If i remember right i generated Order resource with scaffolding. However , when i created by hand new resources (not using scaffolding)
i had a different route for my resource. For example , i have something like `name_resource_show(:id)` for the show. This kind of style is good cause i understand that i have to pass the id , if i want to see a specific resource. But in the case before , the case of `order` , i really don't know how rails is able to understand to use the id of the object order. And also:
why i have different routes name? why i have sometimes `_path` and sometimes (maybe when i generate resource with scaffolding) other things?
i would expect something like `order_show(:id)` and not simply `order`.
how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails helpers are smart enough to use model object to form url.

`<%= link_to 'Mostra', order %>`  equivalent to `<%= link_to 'Mostra', order_path(order) %>` and both points to order show page.

This will generate 7 routes for your controller orders.

```
resources :orders
```

**order**  GET  /orders/:id orders#show

Here **order** is the helper method it provides to call routes instead of using /orders/:id.

Simply you can use order_path(order) to get route `/orders/:id`

Similary we get helper for all 7 routes. You can also override the helpers.

Go to below link for more information.

**Reference:** http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend following the Rails conventions on routes (see the [main reference article here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)).

Here are answers to your questions in order.

- The route you got from `rake routes` makes sense in the following way. Look at the URL (`orders/:id`). Within all of your orders, the `:id` passed specifies which one to look at. The `GET` nature of the request indicates you are getting the data on that record, i.e. that it is a SHOW action.
- Rails understands where the ID is because of how the routes are structured. If you had `order GET /orders/:year/:id` in routes, then Rails will know to look for the third parameter for the ID it needs.
- The two for accessing routes options are `_path` and `_url` ([see here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939865/named-routes-path-vs-url)), but there are some alternatives explained in the main reference article I linked at top.
- You can still use the explicit route, but the `order` option is simply a bit of sugar Rails offers to make things easier to read.