# Rails redirect_to creates wrong URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, controller

Haven't been able to find anything specific to this issue (other searches deal with forms and such).  It's probably a simple oversight on my part.  But what on earth am I missing?

**GOAL:** I'm simply trying to redirect from the `/login` page URL to the `/dashboard` URL if a session exists.

**EXPECTED OUTCOME:**  Calling `redirect_to dashboard_index_url` or `redirect_to '/dashboard'` should go to `https://mydomain/dashboard`

**CURRENT OUTCOME:** if I go to `https://mydomain` after creating a session it redirects me to `https://mydomaindashboard`, note the missing slash

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS:**

- Manually type the URL https://mydomain/dashboard after creating a session, **RESULT:** works, *so the proper route seems to exist*
- Make manual route in `routes.rb`, **RESULT:** behavior is exactly the same as `resource` routing with the missing slash
- Clear browser cache, use different browswers **RESULT:** all exhibit same behavior

Here's what I have (abbreviated to relevant parts):

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to dashboard_index_url if session[:user_id]
  end
  #...
end

class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_login # calls redirect_to root_url unless session[:user_id]

  def index
    #...
  end
end

# In routes.rb:
resources :login
resources :dashboard
# have also tried things like (removed the above line for these)
get 'dashboard' => "dashboard#index"
```

---

@Ryan  Here is the current output for the routes:

`$ rake routes
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
    login_index GET    /login(.:format)              login#index
                POST   /login(.:format)              login#create
      new_login GET    /login/new(.:format)          login#new
     edit_login GET    /login/:id/edit(.:format)     login#edit
          login GET    /login/:id(.:format)          login#show
                PATCH  /login/:id(.:format)          login#update
                PUT    /login/:id(.:format)          login#update
                DELETE /login/:id(.:format)          login#destroy
      dashboard GET    /dashboard(.:format)          dashboard#index
dashboard_index GET    /dashboard(.:format)          dashboard#index
                POST   /dashboard(.:format)          dashboard#create
  new_dashboard GET    /dashboard/new(.:format)      dashboard#new
 edit_dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id/edit(.:format) dashboard#edit
                GET    /dashboard/:id(.:format)      dashboard#show
                PATCH  /dashboard/:id(.:format)      dashboard#update
                PUT    /dashboard/:id(.:format)      dashboard#update
                DELETE /dashboard/:id(.:format)      dashboard#destroy
           root GET    /                             login#index`

Comment: Could you add the output of `rake routes`.

Comment: in your `routes.rb`, do you have your root set? 
Example: `root :to => 'home#index'`

Comment: @musicman3569 did you tried to use path over url?

Comment: @TetianaChupryna what do you mean `path over url`? I'm new to rails.

Comment: @musicman3569 check out my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED:**

Well, I found the problem and it was not actually Rails, it was Apache-Passenger.  There was a config with a redirect (so that all HTTP get redirected to HTTPS) at the apache level that didn't have the trailing slash floating around and causing trouble. (smacks forehead)

Gotta love those red herrings.  Thanks so much guys for the quick help!

Answer (score 1):

for use dashboard_index_url, you have to write it in your routes file. However as you've created in *routes.rb* a **dashboard resource**, a *dashboards_url* is available to you and it leads to */dashboards/index*

Other way to nail this task is create a mapping

```
get 'dashboard' => "dashboard#index" as: :dashboard_index
```

and *dashboard_index_url* and *dashboard_index_path* will be available for you

**Update 1**

Please, look on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939865/named-routes-path-vs-url)
the problem is that path give you relative route and url - absolute. that's why you don't have additional slash in your path. Try **path** instead of **url** and it should work.

**Update 2**

try *dashboard_index_path*

Comment: For some reasone, even if I do that or use `redirect_to '/dashboard/index'` directly and not the variable it still strips that leading space so that I get `https://mydomaindashboard/index`, argh

Comment: Great suggestion and thanks for the quick responses.  Unfortunately using `redirect_to dashboard_index_path` goes to `https://mydomaindashboard` with no slash as well.  Yet manually adding the slash and reloading gives me the proper page.  I'm truly stumped.

Comment: it was Apache that was the problem, I posted the solution below.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your routes to

`get '/login', to: redirect('/dashboard')`

You can even tailor the resulting link to something more specific to your user by

`get '/login', to: redirect('/dashboard'), as: '/dashboard/user[:username]'` if you need to.

On a side-note, you should try cleaning up your routes as you go. There are a lot there that you are not using. Change it to
`resources :dashboard, only: [:index]` and add to it as you need. E.g `only: [:index, :show]` etc. If another developer was needed to modify your app one day we'd look at your routes and perhaps make incorrect assumptions about what we can do.

Justin