# When is `_path_url` required when linking inside a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

When is it required to use `_path_url` instead of `_path` inside an application?

My understanding was that `_path` provides a relative path inside of a site, where `_url` is required when linking between different sites.

**Source:** [Named routes _path vs _url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939865/named-routes-path-vs-url)

But I'm getting the below error in my application when linking to another page.

**Error:**

> undefined method `users_show_path' for #<#:0x007fe12740c3a0> Did you mean?  users_show_path_url

**routes.rb**

```
get '/user/:id/show', to: 'users#show', as: :users_show_path
```

**Working link**

```
<%= link_to 'Return', users_show_path_url(current_user), class: 'btn btn-default'  %>
```

**Failing link**

```
<%= link_to 'Return', users_show_path(current_user), class: 'btn btn-default'  %>
```

Adding `_url` was required to make it work.

I've never had this issue before in Rails development so I'm wondering if there is some routing technicality that might be causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a **guess**

```
<%= link_to 'Return', users_show_path_path(current_user), class: 'btn btn-default'  %>
```

Why do you need **as: :users_show_path** make it **as: :users_show**

Then your code will work otherwise you can use **users_show_path_path** which is funny..