# Ruby on Rails tutorial: difference between route_path and route_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

What is the difference between `<route>_path` and `<route>_url` in the Ruby on Rails?

For example, we use `route_path` and `route_url` in the `route.rb` file of the rails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Named routes \_path vs \_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939865/named-routes-path-vs-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*_path` returns just a path part of the url, e.g. `/documents/1`, `*_url` gives you full URL with protocol and host `https://myapp.com/documents/1`